# Can someone help me identify this Brazilian spider?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arachnology

Does anyone know anything about the identification of this spider? Sorry, but it's the only image I have. It was shot at 2004, January 25th (summer), at 11:27 AM, in Cerrado biome at Minas Gerais state, Brazil. It was walking over a *Paepalanthus* inflorescence (Eriocaulaceae), probably waiting to prey on its pollinators. A small section of web can be seen raised to the left (where it apparently comes from another inflorescence), touches one of the small flowers, and then it's apparently still connected to the spider, in a pattern that reminds me of Salticidae, though I'm not sure. I think its size is around 1 cm. I doubt a specific identification will be possible, but family, superfamily, subfamily, anything will be fine.

[image: Brazilian spider]

Answer (score 2):

Interesting!  See those long spines on the legs?  Only two groups of spiders (that come to mind, anyway) have that sort of arrangement:
Lynx Spiders (Family Oxyopidae) and Pirate Spiders (Family Mimetidae).
Lynx Spiders are wandering hunters, and the ones I'm familiar with tend to have a body shape more like the familiar Grass Spiders (longish, tear-drop shaped abdomen and hunters cephalothorax - roughly rectangular, and often very blocky at the face.
For instance:
https://bugguide.net/node/view/1965
[image: Oxyopes sp.]

https://bugguide.net/node/view/1489229/bgimage

So, your spider looks to be a South American Lynx Spider, which unfortunately I'm not at all knowledgeable about.

I'm going to discount Pirate Spiders as a possibility, even with the association there with a bit of web (Pirate Spiders invade other species' webs and kill the occupants), because they're much more 'orb-weaver'-like in their general body shape.  This one is so Lynx Spider-like that I am pretty confident that it is one of those.